# PHP error Undefined index in

Tags: php

Error:

[image: Image of the error]

Code:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['submit']) {
    $ename = $_REQUEST['ename'];
    $civstatus = $_REQUEST['civstatus'];
    $deptno = $_REQUEST['deptno'];
    $hiredate = $_REQUEST['hiredate'];
    $sal = $_REQUEST['sal'];
    $comm = $_REQUEST['comm'];

    include("conn.php");
    $sql = "insert into emp
            (ename,civstatus,
             deptno,hiredate,
             sal,comm) values(
             '$ename','$civstatus',
             '$deptno','$hiredate',
             '$sal','$comm')";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);  
    $conn->close();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please make it a little clear

Comment: I add some image of the error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider: pasting the same thing over and over doesn't encourage people to help you because it's annoying, like typing in ALL CAPS

Comment: If you are using post then i suggest you to user $_POST instead of $_REQUEST.

Comment: And please also show me your conn.php code.

Comment: Sorry because i cant it says it needs to add some more context, im new here at stackoverflow. Im sorry

Comment: use if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Comment: the (isset) works! thanks!

Comment: BTW, can you help me to post the code right? because stackoverflow is not a userfriendly forum

Comment: @stackoverlow upvote it if u find my suggestion helpful :)

Comment: @stackoverlow what you want to edit in this ?

Comment: I mean how to properly post code here in stackoverflow

Comment: @stackoverflow when you post credentials, make sure to shadow your password; for instance, $user: mysql*** $pass: !sed*** and hide any urls, especially directing to your webserver or your home network.

Comment: thansk for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

first in your form please check your submit button have name="submit" and in your php code please use isset. try this-

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ename = $_REQUEST['ename'];
    $civstatus = $_REQUEST['civstatus'];
    $deptno = $_REQUEST['deptno'];
    $hiredate = $_REQUEST['hiredate'];
    $sal = $_REQUEST['sal'];
    $comm = $_REQUEST['comm'];

    include("conn.php");
    $sql = "insert into emp
            (ename,civstatus,
             deptno,hiredate,
             sal,comm) values(
             '$ename','$civstatus',
             '$deptno','$hiredate',
             '$sal','$comm')";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);  
    $conn->close();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check name of input elements of all the form fields are same as you are using in php file.

You need to improve your code by checking the values availability like-

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $ename = isset($_REQUEST['ename']) ? $_REQUEST['ename'] : '';
    $civstatus = isset($_REQUEST['civstatus']) ? $_REQUEST['civstatus'] : '';
    $deptno = isset($_REQUEST['deptno']) ? $_REQUEST['deptno'] : 0;
    $hiredate = isset($_REQUEST['hiredate']) ? $_REQUEST['hiredate'] : '';
    $sal = isset($_REQUEST['sal']) ? $_REQUEST['sal'] : 0;
    $comm = isset($_REQUEST['comm']) ? $_REQUEST['comm'] : ''; 

    include("conn.php");

    $sql = "insert into emp
            (ename,civstatus,
             deptno,hiredate,
             sal,comm) values(
             $ename,$civstatus,
             $deptno,$hiredate,
             $sal,$comm)";

    $res = $conn->query($sql);  
    $conn->close();
  }
?>
```

You also need to check conn.php file for any undefined index .